# AVAudioPlayer: How to Change the Playback Speed of Audio?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I want to control the playback speed of audio in `AVAudioplayer`. Is this possible? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: Look into the API of AVAudioplayer.

Comment: Looks like it works for iOS5 - [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) and look at **rate**. thanks,

Answer (score 35):

Now it is possible to change the playback speed.

Sample code:

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
player.volume = 0.4f;
player.enableRate = YES; //<--
[player prepareToPlay];
[player setNumberOfLoops:0];
player.rate = 2.0f; //<-- Playback Speed
[player play];
```

**`enableRate`** is set to `YES` and you can change it.

See more in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I can confirm that this works like a charm in iOS 6. Set enableRate to YES, and you can adjust the value of rate between 0.5 and 2.0 (half speed to double speed) with no pitch correction necessary. It can even be adjusted DURING playback, as long as you set enableRate before you start playing the audio.

Answer (score 17):

## Swift 2 - Swift 5

#### You can increase the rate by doing this:

```
player.enableRate = true
player.prepareToPlay()
player.rate = 2.0
player.play()
```

#### If you want to loop, you can add this:

```
player.numberOfLoops = 3
```

Comment: Is the opposite possible `player.rate = 0.8`?

Comment: I think so! You can try it, it's pretty quick :)

Comment: how can I get second of song played or better milisecond?

Comment: downvoted. `enableRate` should be set before calling `prepareToPlay()`. see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1387084-enablerate)

Comment: Sure @Adam thanks for pointing it out. Next time, feel free to improve the answer by editing it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
audioP = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: selectedPath), fileTypeHint: "caf")
        audioP.enableRate = true
        audioP.prepareToPlay()
        audioP.rate = 1.5
        audioP.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can only change the volume not the speed of playback.

I think to do that, you will have to use the much lower level *Audio Queue* APIs and manipulate the audio stream manually to apply that effect.

Comment: As of 2014 (and probably much earlier), this is not true.

Comment: No it will now work fine, Check the doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#jumpTo_15

Answer (score 1):

set enableRate = YES and then you can adjust the rate between 0.1 and 2.0 for slowed down and sped up (1.0 is normal speed)

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayer does not support playback speed setting. Audio Queue Services are quite a pain to use, so that you might want to try OpenAL. See the sound engine from [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) or [Finch](http://github.com/zoul/Finch) for examples of how to wrap OpenAL in Objective-C.