# Is it possible to change the audio play speed with AVAudioPlayer in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer, playback

I'm  playing a local mp3 file with class 'AVAudioPlayer'  on my iOS App.
And I want to change the speed when play it. such as I want to play this mp3 file slower.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Now it is possible to change the speed of sound.

here is my sample code:

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
        player.volume = 0.4f;
        player.enableRate=YES;
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
        player.rate=2.0f;
        [player play];
```

you set "enableRate" to YES and you can change it.

see more docs

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with AVAudioPlayer. See [AVAudioPlayer: How to Change the Playback Speed of Audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350657/avaudioplayer-how-to-change-the-playback-speed-of-audio) for potential workarounds.