# iphone audio speed control programmatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, avaudioplayer, ios-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AVAudioPlayer: How to Change the Playback Speed of Audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350657/avaudioplayer-how-to-change-the-playback-speed-of-audio)

I want to control the speed of the audio played by AVAudioPlayer, So is it possible to control the speed of the audio from slider controller?

Answer (score 0):

I got solution with the help of OpenAL only. With the help of SimpleAudioEngine n CDAudioManager I have done it. referance link : http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/CocosDenshion/html/interface_simple_audio_engine.html