# Custom control for playback speed for AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayerviewcontroller

1. Can we add custom playback speed (0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0) control to **`AVPlayerViewController`**?
2. Is there a way we can refresh speed rate using an `UISlider` value change?
3. Can we change the playback speed if it is playing currently?

Comment: Here's an answer to part of your question regarding if it's possible to change the speed and how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220680/3487310

Comment: Thank you for help.it worked.

Comment: @ZeeshanBadshah did you managed to add a custom playback speed control to `AVPlayerViewController`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Can we add custom playback speed (0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0) control to **`AVPlayerViewController`**?

You can add a custom playback speed button to **`AVPlayerViewController`** by doing a little hack.

In iOS 11, i.e., you can add a button to the `AVPlayerViewController` by adding the control next to the "*Play/Pause*" button. That button has an Accessible Identifier which will help you find that control.

[image: iOS 11 AVPlayerViewController]

So, what I did was basically find that "*Play/Pause*" button and add my Playback Speed button to the superview of the "*Play/Pause*" button.

```
func findPlayPauseButton(view: UIView) -> UIView? {
    if view.accessibilityIdentifier == "Play/Pause" {
        return view
    }
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let result = findPlayPauseButton(view: subview) {
            return result
        }
    }
    return nil
}

guard let playerView = playerViewController?.view else {
    return
}

guard let playPauseButton = findPlayPauseButton(view: playerView) else {
    return
}

if let playerControlsView = playPauseButton.superview {
    let playbackSpeedButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    playbackSpeedButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "PlaybackSpeed"
    playbackSpeedButton.setTitle("1 X", for: .normal)
    playbackSpeedButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playbackSpeedButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    playbackSpeedButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    playerControlsView.addSubview(playbackSpeedButton)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        playbackSpeedButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playPauseButton.heightAnchor),
        playbackSpeedButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        playbackSpeedButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playPauseButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 70),
        playbackSpeedButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playPauseButton.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Playback Speed Button Example]

As you may know, this has a lot of downsides because of all the edge cases that you will find, i.e., you need to take care the landscape as well, you need to check if the hack is still valid on every new iOS version, etc. If you app supports iOS 10, then things are different because the UI of the `AVPlayerViewController` has changed in iOS 11.

> 2. Is there a way we can refresh speed rate using an UISlider value change?

Yes, instead of a `UIButton` for changing the playback speed, just add an `UISlider`.

> 3. Can we change the playback speed if it is playing currently?

Yes, if it's playing then you just need to change the [`rate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388846-rate) property of the player: for example to 1.25 X => `playerViewController.player?.rate = 1.25`.

#### UPDATE:

Enhancement requested!  Radar number is 46022646: [Playback speed control for AVPlayerViewController (Video)](http://rdar://46022646).