# SwiftUI - Adding playback rate control in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

I am using an AVPlayer in my current SwiftUI project. I am trying to implement a playback speed control similar to what Apple has on its video player for the Developer App (like in the given screenshot) but found no answers so far.
Any leads on the matter would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Here's my code for the video player so far.

```
import AVKit

struct pipPlayer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoUrl: URL = URL(string: "Video Link")!

    // Create the player and set the basic controls
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<pipPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        let player1 = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
        controller.player = player1
        controller.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
        controller.player!.play()
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<pipPlayer>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem some month ago. I didn't found any way to do this natively, so I ended up hiding the native controls of AVPlayerViewController and creating my own controls from scratch. But this is a really poor solution cause native controls have lots of functionalities that would take a lot of time to fully replace them

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36848244/3151675