# How to play audio with different speed?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

For example, play a local audio file with double speed or half speed.
I've already checked several Github projects, but none of them supports that.
Any idea about how to make it will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350657/avaudioplayer-how-to-change-the-playback-speed-of-audio

Comment: Use AVPlayer and set rate to 2

Comment: Do you used `AVAudioPlayer`?

Answer (score 1):

```
player.rate = 2.0 // Whatever speed you want
```

Assuming you're using AVAudioPlayer. you can change speed by changing the rate.

detail doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer#jumpTo_15

Comment: Make sure set `player.enableRate = true` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to change the speed of sound.

here is my sample code:

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&err];
    player.volume = 0.4f;
    player.enableRate=YES;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player setNumberOfLoops:0];
    player.rate=2.0f;
    [player play];
```

you set "enableRate" to YES and you can change it.

Comment: Stop copy paste from another posts, you can share the link directly.